# Login with Facebook to my Django Website through Android App

Tags: android, django, facebook, authentication, token

I have:

- A Website with Django: It has [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth); I can connect with it with regular login plus facebook login, and they work fine through browsers (Cookies authentication).
- I'm building an Android App that should provide login, signup, password reset and API consumption of my Website; It seems like I should use Token Authentication for mobile;
  For the regular token-Login I will use [django rest framework Token Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) , because:

If successfully authenticated, TokenAuthentication provides the following credentials.

> request.user will be a Django User instance.
>
> request.auth will be a rest_framework.authtoken.models.BasicToken instance.

Which I need to manage user's actions.
Thus, I will create a separate API for token-regular-login for the mobile App users. The token will be generated on server side when the user provide correct username and password, then it will be returned to it (mobile App) to send it back to server on each request requiring authentication.

All these should go fine, But, the problem, is how to login to my website with Facebook through my mobile App, the mobile App should have a connect with Facebook Button, which enable users to connect using their Facebook Account (Maybe they will be asked to confirm by Facebook)

I need to know how this would be possible, and I would like to get:

> request.user will be a Django User instance. within each request
> performed.

- Not interested in PhoneGap.
- For Internet Browser Users (Web) I will not change anything.